# Why my formula is not working in Flow

Tags: formula, screen-flow

I have this formula :

```
IF(
    ISBLANK({!recordid.Bill_To_Country__c}), 
    "<li><strong>Please Enter a Bill To Country</strong></li>", 
    " "
)
```

and I am using it on a Screen Flow.

When the field 'Bill to Country' is not populated I want the message error to come up on the Screen but when the same field is populated I don't want the message to come up. At the moment the message stays there even if the field is populated. What am I doing wrong? Please help.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, could you add a direct reference to {!recordid.Bill_To_Country__c} in a display text component to see what the value is at that point?

Comment: Fantastic! I suspected the `{!recordid}` variable wasn't getting set. FYI, if you end up wanting to use this Flow from a Flow Action (eg button in the Highlights Panel), you'll need to update the name of your variable to `recordId` with a capital `I`, as it is case sensitive